# Woher kommt das Adjektiv "vollschlank"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-classes

Woher kommt das Adjektiv *vollschlank*?

Warum bedeutet es quasi das Gegenteil von dem, was es ausdrückt?
Wie nennt man solche Wörter?

Comment: Ich verstehe das als eine Art ironische Wortbildung. Der Ursprung würde mich aber wirklich interessieren.

Comment: Interessant zu erfahren, dass es sich tatsächlich um einen Euphemismus für *pummelig* handelt.. Hab's bisher immer als *schlank* verstanden (Also *voll schlank*, was gesprochen bekräftigend wirkt, wie *total schlank*).

Comment: Ich bezweifle den Euphemismus. Gibt es hier eine Quelle? Mir ist der Begriff bisher nur begegnet als Abstufung zwischen (sehr) schlanken ud dicken Menschen, meist für Frauen gebraucht, im selben Sinne, wie man bei Männern eher von einer *normalen Figur* sprechen würde.

Comment: "... Vollschlank ..., weil es nur eine Bedeutung hat." Widerspruch. Dieser müsste nicht begründet sein da, ein aus 'voll' und 'schlank' gebildetes Adjektiv "völlig / ganz und gar schlank bedeutet. Dieses Wort kommt eher aus einer unteren stilistischen Schicht, wie z.B.: "voi*fett" für besoffen, und unterschwellig schwingt Bosheit mit? Wo sind für Wortneuschöpfungen bzw. Wortkehrungen etymologische Beschreibungen? Sind die voi*schlank?
* voll

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wikipedia nennt als Herkunftsangabe:

> Das Wort „vollschlank“ ist in der Zeit um die Wende vom 19. zum 20. Jahrhundert entstanden, als „voll-“, aus der Wirtschaftssprache kommend, allgemein eine Intensivierung ausdrückte, wie etwa in den bis heute üblichen Wörtern „Vollmilch“, „Volldampf“ oder „vollinhaltlich“. Vgl. Lutz Mackensen: Die deutsche Sprache unserer Zeit. Quelle & Meyer, Heidelberg 1956, S. 74.

Diese Angabe stammt aus dem [Artikel über Euphemismus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemismus), wo vollschlank als Beispiel genannt wird. Allerdings bezeichnet ein Euphemismus allgemein einen sprachlichen „Ausdruck, der eine Person, eine Personengruppe, einen Gegenstand oder einen Sachverhalt beschönigend, mildernd oder in verschleiernder Absicht benennt“, und nicht konkret ein Wort, dessen (teilweises) Gegenteil gemeint ist. *Vollschlank* ist ein Euphemismus; die Bedeutung als rhetorische Figur (*Oxymoron*) beschreibt splattne in seiner Antwort. Allerdings bin ich gar nicht sicher, ob es ein Oxymoron ist (siehe Kommentare).

Comment: Während du geantwortet hast, habe ich auch noch mal nachgedacht und die Prioritäten in meiner Antwort vertauscht.

Comment: +1 Die Herkunft war mir neu. PS: voll krass. ;) Obwohl: gibt's in Wikipedia eine Quelle dafür? Wieso voll...**schlank**?

Comment: @splattne: Vollfett wäre ja eher unglücklich, oder? Soll ja verhüllen oder wenigstens mildern. *Voll* scheint ja weniger, wie in deiner Antwort zum Oxymoron beschrieben, von füllig zu kommen, als vielmehr von der Intensivierung. So gesehen ist es vielleicht gar kein Oxymoron, sondern bedeutet lediglich komplett das Gegenteil (dieser Herleitung nach bedeutet vollschlank ja quasi *sehr schlank*). Auch da kenne ich aber den Begriff für die rhetorische Figur nicht ;) Ja, die Quelle habe ich ja zitiert, *Die deutsche Sprache unserer Zeit*.

Comment: Ich bezweifle die in Wikipedia zitierte Quelle (Herkunft): http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=vollschlank&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3 - der Graph bestärkt mein Bauchgefühl, dass es ein "Scherzbegriff" des 20. Jh. ist.

Comment: Naja, in der Quelle steht, dass es um die Jahrhundertwende entstanden ist. NGrams zeigt eine schriftliche Verwendung ab 1920, völlig absurd finde ich das so gesehen nicht. Andererseits hat Herr Mackensen vielleicht auch ein wenig geraten ;)

Comment: Interessant finde ich, dass es im DWB auftaucht: "-schlank, adj., neues modewort, das richtige schönheitsmasz der weiblichen fülle bei schlankheit bezeichnend." - leider steht dort nicht, wie alt der Eintrag ist. Zu Lebzeiten sind die Brüder Grimm ja nur bis F gekommen. Die Beschreibung im Grimm klingt aber nicht nach Spaßwort.

Comment: Du hast mich beinahe überzeugt. :)

Answer (score 12):

Das Wort *vollschlank* ist eine **beschönigende Bezeichnung** (Euphemismus) für *dick* (oder *fett*) und wird meist mit einem Augenzwinkern verwendet.

Ich glaube auch, dass das Wort ein **Oxymoron** ist. Darunter versteht man eine rhetorische Figur, bei der eine Formulierung aus zwei gegensätzlichen, einander widersprechenden oder sich gegenseitig ausschließenden Begriffen gebildet wird. In unserem Fall werden die Begriffe *voll* (im Sinne von füllig, mollig) und *schlank* zu einem gewollten Widerspruch zusammengefasst.

---

**Update**

Ich bin nicht überzeugt von der Herkunft des Wortes, wie sie in der Quelle im Wikipedia-Artikel über Euphemismus angegeben ist. Dieser Google-Ngram-Graph legt nahe, dass das Wort erst im 20. Jahrhundert aufkam:

[image: ngram vollschlank Gebrauch in deutschen Büchern]

([Link zum Google-Ngram-Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vollschlank&year_start=1890&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3))

Comment: Ebenfalls +1. Ich glaube schon, dass der Euphemismus zunächst das entscheidende ist. Im Kommentar zu meiner Antwort stelle ich die These auf, dass es gar kein Oxymoron ist.

Answer (score 3):

Zur Herkunft kann ich nicht viel neues sagen. In einem Kommentar wurde schon einmal [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=vollschlank) erwähnt:

> -schlank, *adj., neues modewort, das richtige schönheitsmasz der weiblichen fülle bei schlankheit bezeichnend.*

Laut [dieser Seite](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GV11232&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&mainmode=DWBLieferungen) ist dieser Abschnitt 1933 fertiggestellt worden. Das passt zu dem NGram, das @splattne in seiner Antwort anführt, und würde nahelegen, dass die in der [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemismus#cite_ref-9) angeführte Quelle um vielleicht 20-25 Jahre daneben liegt. Jedenfalls würde es mich wundern, wenn ein um 1900 enstandenes Wort gut 30 Jahre später noch als "neues Modewort" bezeichnet würde.

Aber Du hast noch zwei andere Fragen gestellt:

> Warum bedeutet es quasi das Gegenteil von dem was es ausdrückt?
>   Wie nennt man solche Worte?

Falls Du damit andeuten willst, dass das Wort allein aufgrund seiner Bestandteile etwas wie "sehr schlank" ausdrückt, so würde ich das als eine falsche Annahme zurückweisen. Die Regeln, wie im Deutschen Zusammensetzungen gebildet werden, sind so frei, dass man aus den Bestandteilen eines Kompositums nicht direkt auf seine Bedeutung schließen kann. Jemand, der *saumselig* ist, ist nicht unbedingt selig. *Altklug* ist etwas ganz anderes als *altersweise*, *unheimlich* nicht das Gegenteil von *heimlich*, *ober-* hat in *obergärig* eine andere Funktion als in *oberfaul*. Vergleiche auch *besenrein* und *stubenrein* oder *unfertig*, *schlüsselfertig* und *schlagfertig*. Ein aus *voll* und *schlank* gebildetes Adjektiv *könnte* zwar bedeuten "völlig / ganz und gar schlank" - aber es muss es nicht, und deshalb halte ich es für folgerichtig, dass es dafür keine spezielle Bezeichnung gibt.

Was es aber gibt, sind Wörter, die mehrere Bedeutungen haben, von denen zwei ein Gegensatzpaar bilden. *Droge* z.B. kann ein *Heil*mittel bezeichnen oder ein Rausch*gift*, *umfahren* das Passieren eines Hindernisses oder die Kollision mit selbigem. Solche Wörter nennt man [Januswörter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Januswort) oder Autoantonyme. *Vollschlank* alleine kommt dafür nicht in Frage, weil es nur eine Bedeutung hat. Wenn wir es aber mit dem Begriff *Wort* nicht so ganz genau nehmen, könnte man sagen, dass die Wortgruppe *voll schlank* und das Adjektiv *vollschlank* zusammen eine Art Januswort bilden.

Abgesehen davon stimme ich natürlich den anderen Antworten zu, die das Wort als Euphemismus einordnen - für seine heutige Verwendung und unsere heutigen Vorstellungen und Bewertung von Schlankheit. Wenn ich mir den Eintrag im Grimm so ansehe, bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob das damals auch schon so gesehen wurde. Ich finde, man könnte ihn auch lesen als

> *schlank* plus soviel Fülle, dass eine schöne Figur dabei herauskommt

Oder anders ausgedrückt: wenn Schlankheit damals gar nicht so das Schönheitsideal war, dann war *vollschlank* vielleicht gar nicht beschönigend, sondern abmildernd und sogar "verbessernd" gemeint. *Voll* könnte dann tatsächlich, wie in der Quelle des Wikipedia-Artikels genannt, als Intensivierung gebraucht worden sein, aber nicht im Sinne von "besonders", sondern eher von "noch besser als".

Answer (score 1):

Warum so kompliziert? Vollschlank ist etwas mehr als schlank aber nicht dick. Eine vollschlanke Frau hat weibliche Rundungen ist weich und nicht dünn. Dick wäre dann korpulent.

Comment: Servus und willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Nimm dir die Zeit für eine [tour] unserer Seite. Bei Fragen, besuche das [help]. Der Fragesteller hier *weiß* um die Bedeutung des Wortes, möchte aber wissen, woher es kommt und warum es nicht »mehr als schlank« bedeutet, wie man es von ähnlichen Begriffen (»voll krass«) erwarten könnte. In dem Sinne geht deine Antwort leider an der Frage vorbei. Im Übrigen verstehe ich *vollschlank* als Synonym für *dick*, nicht für das, was du beschreibst.

Comment: Das beantwortet nicht die Frage, woher das Wort kommt.

Comment: Ich muss sagen, dass ich das Wort auch in der Weise gelernt habe, die Du darlegst, bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob es nicht doch ironisch ist, oder ein Euphemismus.